# If someone uses all of their flags, are they not allowed to flag anymore?

Tags: support, flagging

I just flagged something as opinion based and used one of my flags. This is my first time using flags, so I'm wondering if I use all ten (not that I plan to go on a flagging rampage) will I be put on a cool down or not allowed to flag anymore?

Comment: It's per-day, but you may get a notice from the mods if most/all are declined (aka _not_ helpful flags). You also get [more flags per day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits) depending on reputation and past flag record.

Comment: Nice username btw ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Flag limits

See [How many flags does a user have per day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149659/278659) and [On the recent changes to flagging and limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185888/278659) on main meta. You get a **fixed flag allowance each day, varying from 10 to 100**:

> - default 10 per day
> - one bonus flag per 2000 reputation
> - one bonus flag for every 10 net helpful flags (helpful - declined)
> - maximum 100

Once you've used up your flags for the day, you won't be able to flag again until the next (UTC) day. That's not a punishment; it's just to ensure that the flag queue doesn't get completely flooded in a short period of time. Note that if enough of your flags are marked helpful, you may get *new* flags in a given day even if you ran out earlier, by the third bullet point!

### Flag bans

It *is* possible to get blocked from flagging for more than a day, but that's never permanent (it lasts a week at most, unless you raise even more bad flags) and only happens if you have too many *declined* flags. From [this canonical main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/278659) (which also contains screenshots):

> Flaggers with a recent (past 7 days) flagging history consisting of at least 10 handled flags where >= 10% of flags were declined will see [a warning] when they flag.
>
> Those who've had 25% or more of their flags declined will [...] be unable to flag any further posts for any reason.

This *does* feel more like a punishment, but if it does happen, think of it as more like a notification that you're not flagging as carefully as you could be. The advice to review your own flagging history is genuine, and meta is always there for you if you need advice. And it's unlikely to happen anyway if you flag sensibly - flags raised in good faith are usually marked helpful.

Comment: I have 100 flags remaining. I'm tempted to flag some more stuff just for the sheer joy of it.

Comment: I flagged some stuff but now I'm back at a hundred again. It's like the Magic Porridge Pot.